# Знаки вопроса на странице html, сгенерированной с помощью python

Tags: html, python

Вообщем, единственная проблема в том, что на странице html, которую генерирует код python, знаки вопроса. ( Кодировка  utf-8 поставлена )
Вот коды:

1. generate_index.py

   ```
   from datetime import datetime as dt
   from horoscope import generate_prophecies

   #body = generate_body(header="Гороскоп на 2012-12-12", paragraphs=generated_prophecies)

   def generate_head(title):
       head =  "<meta charset='utf-8'>" + "<title>" + title + "</title>" 
       return "<head>" + head + "</head>"

   def generate_page(head, body):
       page = "<html>" + head + body + "</html>"
       return page



   def generate_body(header, paragraphs):
       body = "<h1>" + header + "</h1>"
       for p in paragraphs:
           body = body + "<p>" + p + "</p>"
       return "<body>" + body + "</body>"



   def save_page(title, header, paragraphs, output="index.html"):
       fp = open(output, "w")
       today = dt.now().date()
       page = generate_page(
               head= generate_head(title),
               body= generate_body(header=header, paragraphs=paragraphs)
           )
       print(page, file=fp)
       fp.close()

   body = generate_body(header="Гороскоп на 2012-12-12", paragraphs=generate_prophecies())

   today = dt.now().date()
   save_page(
       title="Гороскоп на сегодня",
       header="Что день " + str(today) + " готовит",
       paragraphs=generate_prophecies()
       )
   ```
2. horoscope.py

   ```
   import random

   times = ["утром", "днём", "вечером", "ночью", "после обеда", "перед сном"]
   advices = ["ожидайте", "предостерегайтесь", "будьте открыты для"]
   promises = ["гостей из забытого прошлого", "встреч со старыми знакомыми",
               "неожиданного праздника", "приятных перемен"]


   def generate_prophecies(total_num=5, num_sentences=3):
       prophecies = []

       i = 0
       while i < total_num:
           j = 0
           forecast = ""
           while j < num_sentences:
               t = random.choice(times)
               a = random.choice(advices)
               p = random.choice(promises)

               full_sentence = t.title() + " " + a + " " + p + "."
               if j != num_sentences - 1:
                   full_sentence = full_sentence + " "

               forecast = forecast + full_sentence
               j = j + 1

           prophecies.append(forecast)
           i = i + 1

       return prophecies
   ```

А в самом файле index.html вот что:

`<html><head><meta charset='utf-8'><title>Ãîðîñêîï íà ñåãîäíÿ</title></head><body><h1>×òî äåíü 2020-06-21 ãîòîâèò</h1><p>Âå÷åðîì ïðåäîñòåðåãàéòåñü ïðèÿòíûõ ïåðåìåí. Íî÷üþ áóäüòå îòêðûòû äëÿ ïðèÿòíûõ ïåðåìåí. Íî÷üþ ïðåäîñòåðåãàéòåñü âñòðå÷ ñî ñòàðûìè çíàêîìûìè.</p><p>Äí¸ì îæèäàéòå ïðèÿòíûõ ïåðåìåí. Ïåðåä Ñíîì áóäüòå îòêðûòû äëÿ ãîñòåé èç çàáûòîãî ïðîøëîãî. Ïîñëå Îáåäà áóäüòå îòêðûòû äëÿ íåîæèäàííîãî ïðàçäíèêà.</p><p>Íî÷üþ áóäüòå îòêðûòû äëÿ íåîæèäàííîãî ïðàçäíèêà. Âå÷åðîì áóäüòå îòêðûòû äëÿ ãîñòåé èç çàáûòîãî ïðîøëîãî. Óòðîì ïðåäîñòåðåãàéòåñü âñòðå÷ ñî ñòàðûìè çíàêîìûìè.</p><p>Íî÷üþ îæèäàéòå ïðèÿòíûõ ïåðåìåí. Ïîñëå Îáåäà áóäüòå îòêðûòû äëÿ ïðèÿòíûõ ïåðåìåí. Ïîñëå Îáåäà îæèäàéòå ïðèÿòíûõ ïåðåìåí.</p><p>Íî÷üþ áóäüòå îòêðûòû äëÿ ïðèÿòíûõ ïåðåìåí. Äí¸ì áóäüòå îòêðûòû äëÿ ãîñòåé èç çàáûòîãî ïðîøëîãî. Óòðîì ïðåäîñòåðåãàéòåñü âñòðå÷ ñî ñòàðûìè çíàêîìûìè.</p></body></html>`

Честно говоря, у меня даже нет идей, я код просмотрел несколько раз.

Comment: Забыли прописать кодировку в open

Comment: Ту же самую? urf-8?

Comment: Спасиба, помог)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

При открытии файла на запись нужно указать ту же кодировку, что указана в теге `<meta charset='...'>`, в данном случае - utf-8:

```
def save_page(title, header, paragraphs, output="index.html"):
    fp = open(output, "w", encoding='utf-8')
    today = dt.now().date()
    page = generate_page(
            head= generate_head(title),
            body= generate_body(header=header, paragraphs=paragraphs)
        )
    print(page, file=fp)
    fp.close()
```